# Solving shortest path problem with Dijkstra’s algorithm for n negative-weight edges and no negative-weight cycle

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstras-algorithm

Although many texts state Dijkstra's algorithm does not work for negative-weight edges, the modification of Dijkstra's algorithm can. Here is the algorithm to solve a single negative-weight edge without negative-weight cycle.

Let $d_s(v)$ be the shortest distance from source vertex s to vertex v.
 Suppose the negative edge $e$ is $(u, v)$
First, remove the negative edge $e$, and run Dijkstra from the source vertex s.
Then, check if $d_s(u) + w(u, v) \leq d_s(v)$. If not, we are done. If yes, then run Dijkstra from $v$, with the negative edge still removed.
Then, $\forall t \in V $, $d(t) = min(d_s(t), d_s(u) + w(u, v) + d_v(t))$

Given the above algorithm, I want to modify the above algorithm again to solve n negative-weight edges and no negative weight cycle. Any hint?

Comment: You write: "... a single negative-weight edge without negative-weight edges."  did you mean "without negative-weight cycles" ?

Comment: @JimN Yes, I mean without negative-weight cycles